# Dynamically sized float expanding beyond container

Tags: html, css

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jr32V/ which contains the following:

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.topmenu, .main {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.topmenu {
    background-color: red;
}

.main {
    background-color: black;
}

.mainpicker {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}

.maincontent {
    width: 600px; /*get rid of this line to see how it should look*/
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="topmenu">
        A whole bunch of menu stuff
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="mainpicker">
            Picker
        </div>
        <div class="maincontent">
            Content on right of picker
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like the "maincontent" div to be exactly to the right of "mainpicker", just as it seems if you remove the width attribute on it.

Note that the width attribute is just to illustrate the point, in actual use the width may go beyond the container by any amount.

Also note that I do not want the parent container ("main") to exactly expand, since it must begin at the same left position as "topmenu". i.e. that they both have the same width vis-a-vis centering/margin-auto calculation

Comment: I edited my answer, have a look :)

Comment: I added a demo. Is that what you require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. Add width and margin to your `.main` class and remove `float:left;` from your `.maincontent` class. I updated your **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jr32V/4/)**

```
.main {
    background-color: black;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.mainpicker {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    width:100px;
}

.maincontent {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to float both children you have to stay inside the given width of you parent class. So your code would look like this:

```
.topmenu {
    background-color: red;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.main {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.mainpicker {
    background-color: green;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}

.maincontent {
    background-color: orange;
    width:400px;
    float:left;
}
```

You can watch it **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/DF3HS/1/)**

Comment: How... does that work? 2 divs next to eachother without float? o_O

Comment: Your `.main` class had a width of 500px. But the children class called `.maincontent` had a width of 600px. So the children is bigger than the parent. If you float it now, it tries to float next to the other div, but the parent div had a fixed width so it cannot get bigger than this width what means it jumps under the first div called `.mainpicker`. I did another fiddle to show it to you. Maybe you understand it better than my explanation :) http://jsfiddle.net/DF3HS/1/

Comment: Oh wait, this doesn't quite work... see: http://jsfiddle.net/jr32V/8/
Should remain on right side completely

Comment: Did you notice my edit and my second jsFiddle? You can either reduce the width of your children div called `.maincontent` or you can increase the width of your parent div called `.main`. Either this: http://jsfiddle.net/jr32V/9/ or this: http://jsfiddle.net/jr32V/11/ if that is what you mean

Comment: Problem is I can't reduce the width of .maincontent (it's actually dynamic- not a set width), and neither can I increase the width of .main unless I just don't set a width on it...

Comment: Just set an extra div around the other ones and set `display:inline-block;`. And then you can add another div around your extra div and set `text-align:center;` You can watch it here: http://jsfiddle.net/DF3HS/3/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jr32V/6/

i put `box-sizing: border-box;` and width as percentages to `mainpicker` and `maincontent`

```
.mainpicker {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    width: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.maincontent {
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

does this help you?

Comment: Unfortunately, the point is that the content of maincontent is dynamic, and WILL go beyond 500px. Giving maincontent a hard width of 600px in the CSS (with the comment to "remove me" to see how it works), was intended to demonstrate that

Answer (score 0):

The following code seemed to do the trick, even though the result doesn't look pleasing to the eye.

```
.mainpicker {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.maincontent {
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/thauwa/jr32V/5/